# Read JSON to add images

Tags: jquery, css, json

I am making an image flow slider. It is working fine if I am hard coding . Now I am using a JSON file to specify how to load images from a gallery. Images are getting loaded successfully but then my external CSS file and jquery are not loaded correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
      $(function(){
          var image= [{
    "src": "images/starting.jpg",
           "data-artist":"Gorillaz",
       "data-album":"Plastic Beach"
             },];

         $.each(image, function(){
       $('<img src="' + this.src+ '"  />').appendTo('#coverflow'); 
        });
   });
```

if i am writting this ,

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="coverflow">
            <img src="img/gorillaz-plasticbeach.jpg" data-artist="Gorillaz" data-album="Plastic Beach"/>-->
            <!--<img src="images/thumb1.jpg" data-artist="Kings Of Leon" data-album="Come Around Sunshine"/>
            <img src="images/thumb2.jpg" data-artist="Kid Rock" data-album="Born Free"/>        
            <img src="images/thumb3.jpg" data-artist="Eminem" data-album="Recovery"/>
            <img src="images/thumb4.jpg" data-artist="Lil Wayne" data-album="I Am Not A Human Being"/>
            <img src="images/thumb5.jpg" data-artist="Taylor Swift" data-album="Speak Now"/>
            <img src="images/thumb6.jpg" data-artist="The Band Perry" data-album="The Band Perry"/>
            <img src="images/thumb7.jpg" data-artist="Maroon 5" data-album="Hands All Over"/>
            <img src="images/thumb8.jpg" data-artist="My Chemical Romance" data-album="Danger Days"/>
            <img src="images/thumb9.jpg" data-artist="Iron Maiden" data-album="The Final Frontier"/>
            <img src="images/thumb10.jpg" data-artist="Order Of The Black" data-album="Black Label Society"/>   
            <img src="images/thumb11.jpg" data-artist="Usher" data-album="Raymond V Raymond"/>-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

then its working perfectly .

i have tried

```
$.each(image, function(){
 $('<img src="' + this.src+ '" />').appendTo('#coverflow');            `$('#coverflow').appendTo('#wrapper');
 $('#wrapper').appendTo('#demo');
 $('#demo').appendTo('#pageWrapper'); }); 
alert ('I am all Done'); 
alert('Elements are ' +$('#coverflow').length); });
```

here i am adding images in div 1 by one. but at the end when i am checking div #coverflow at the end it contents only 1 Element . though loop is iterating 11 times

Comment: OK, so what errors are you seeing with your CSS and jQuery? If you inspect your page, do you see any differences in the generated markup from when you were hard-coding it?

Comment: What do you mean by "are not loaded correctly"? Are them even called? If you go in Source Code and click on the JS and CSS file what happens? What does it show? When you were hard-coding it, were the CSS and jQuery working? Do you have any JavaScript errors that Firebug maybe pointing out?

Comment: All Images are loading successfuly but CSS properties like floating ,transparency are not getting Applied .

Comment: What does your generated markup look like? If your CSS isn't being applied that suggests that there's something out of step between your hard-coded HTML and what you jQuery is inserting.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was clearly wrong. Please try to show your problem better. I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9CbRQ/) to check your usage of image and it worked well. Can you extend the fiddle?

Comment: $.each(image, function(){
       $('<img src="' + this.src+ '"  />').appendTo('#coverflow'); 
             $('#coverflow').appendTo('#wrapper');
             $('#wrapper').appendTo('#demo');
             $('#demo').appendTo('#pageWrapper');
            
            }); 
       
       alert ('I am all Done');
        alert('Elemts are ' +$('#conerflow').length);
      
             });       here i am adding images in div 1 by one. but at the end when i am checking div #coverflow at the end it contens only 1 Element . though loop is iterating 11 times .

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure image (from that "each") is an object that has the src attribute (I know you said it works hardcoded, just make sure it's an object, use console.log(typeof image); before you do the each)
2. .appendTo('#coverflow'); is incorrect, you probably mean .appendTo($('#coverflow')); you can only append stuff to jquery objects (appendTo only works on jQuery objects)
3. start with a simple:

   $.each(image, function(){
   console.log(image.src);
   });

Comment: yes i have checked it with                                       $.each(image, function(){ console.log(image.src); }); ,                                       it is printing src correct .even images are displayed on my page . but i want to check if they are added in div or not because i have written some properties on div tag which should get applied on images  .